# Count register depending of current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table who have creation date like:

```
SELECT [CreationDate] FROM Store.Order
```

So each register have one datetime like:

```
 2018-03-14 00:00:00.000
 2017-04-14 00:00:00.000
 2017-06-14 00:00:00.000
```

I want to know how to `COUNT` only register of Date equals to current month and year, for example in this case,if I only have one 
register in month 03 I just get 1 on count, how can I achieve it? Regards

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Comment: SQL Server @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Store.Order
WHERE
    CONVERT(varchar(7), [CreationDate], 126) = CONVERT(varchar(7), GETDATE(), 126);
```

### Demo

We can convert both the creation date in your table and the current date into `yyyy-mm` strings, and then check if they be equal.

Comment: Can you explain me what 126 does in CONVERT clause?

Comment: @David [Check here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php).  It converts the date to `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss:mmm` format, but then keeps only the first 7 characters, which is `yyyy-mm`.  That is, it gives us the year and month, which is what you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to do:

```
where creationdate >= dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate(), cast(getdate() as date)) and
      creationdate < dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate(), cast(getdate() as date)))
```

Although this looks more complex than other solutions, all the complexity is on `getdate()` -- meaning that the optimizer can use indexes on `creationdate`.